# URL has an invalid label. Not too sure as of why

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-requests, download

```
import requests
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Image Downloader")
window.geometry("800x400")

def download():
    url_entry.get()
    url = ("https://" + str(url_entry))
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open("downloaded_image.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)

url_label = Label(window, text="Enter URL Here:", fg="black", font="Helvetica 14 bold")
url_label.place(x=0, y=0)
url_entry = Entry(window)
url_entry.place(x=155, y=5)
how_to_get_url_label = Label(window, text="Find the image you want to download > right click > copy image address",
                             font="Helvetica 14 bold")
how_to_get_url_label.place(x=0 , y=27)
download_button = Button(window, text="Download", font="Helvetica 9 bold", fg="black", bg="green", pady=-5, padx=-5,
                         command=download)
download_button.place(x=285, y=2.5)

window.mainloop()
```

Gives error message "URL has an invalid label" and I'm not too sure why. I'm attempting to make an image downloader using tkinter and requests together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your definition of download function and assign value returned by Entry.get() method, i.e.:

```
def download():
    url_text = url_entry.get()
    url = ("https://" + str(url_text))
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open("downloaded_image.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Besides that it should work just fine.